# Android HttpURLConnection: Why Linux makes session file in everytimes

Tags: java, php, android, session, httpurlconnection

I'm write a Android App which based LAMP.
There is a login function in the app.
All of operation functions are perfect. But,

> **Why Linux makes session files everytimes
>  only when I connect on phone which utilizing httpURLConnection ???**

When I connect web page **without login** by WebBrowser(Chrome),
The Linux makes Session file it's empty <---(A)

And then, I connect web page **with login** by WebBrowser(Chrome) too,
The Linux makes Session file which appended in the (A) session file.

so. result. If I use webbrowser, linux makes session file, only 1.

**But!

When I connect on the phone(app),

Linux makes session file everytimes If I login,**

It means

App login -> (Linux makes session)
backpress -> App Login -> (Linux makes session)
backpress -> App Login -> (Linux makes session)

** I checked PHPSESSID in Logcat, and Cache SQL, utilizing cookie sync manager

```
Android HttpURLConnection Header Part Source

    URL urlLogin = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlLogin.openConnection();
    httpConn.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setUseCaches(true);
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
```

PHP Login server part

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "dbconn.php";
require_once "check.php";
require_once "process.php";

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];

$process = new Process($_POST);

if ($process->checkLogin()) { //Check Login matches
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['pw'] = $pw;
    $_SESSION['logged'] = true;

    $errcode = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "session file" == "session cookie", perhaps you have not enabled cookie management for `HttpUrlConnection`. As is described [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), you need to use `CookieHandler` and `CookieManager` for this:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Comment: Thnxk, but, CookieHandler.setDefault(NEEDS cookie handler variable)

Comment: and, new CookieManager() <-- showing up this Error: The constructor CookieManager() is not visible

Comment: I suspect you imported the wrong `CookieManager` class. You need `java.net.CookieManager`.

Comment: suck....It was java.net.CookieManager But, It's android SDK version problem....:< it needs 2.3.3 over..... My project based 2.2 !!!!! T_T

Comment: @JuHyunLee: If you are using Android 2.2, please switch to using the HttpClient library built into Android (`org.apache.http`). So long as you reuse the same `HttpClient` object for each request, session cookies will be maintained for you.

Comment: But, I heard about httpClient close() bugs and httpurlconnection is better... I have to think about this problem... thanks very very!